# How can I get the uid of my users from firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am able to anonymously create a user in firebase with the below code but when I try to log the current user's 'uid' in the console it returns 'undefined'. Please advise on my below code.

```
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();

  console.log(userID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to log the UID of the user after they sign in, you have to ways to accomplish that:

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then((credential) => {
  console.log(credential.user.uid);
});
```

This will log the console when the user actively logs in.

---

If you instead want to respond whenever the user signs in or out, you can do:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    console.log(user.uid);
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This second way works even if you restart the app, as Firebase will in that case automatically restore the user's authentication state.

Comment: so I got this issue when I tried the second method (first one gave me an issue as well):

subscribe.ts:239 ReferenceError: credential is not defined
    at Object.next (app.js:24)
    at subscribe.ts:104
    at subscribe.ts:233


Also, in the firebase authentication tab, I can see that the sign in date doesn't seem to update even though I access my app from three different devices. I seems to have logged the users during the creation date and set that as the one and only sign in date. Apologies for the long blurb I tried spacing out properly in this comment.

Comment: Ah, good catch. That error in the second snippet was copy/paste/forgot-to-modify. I updated it now.

Comment: Hey @user3385829. Did the second snippet work with the change?